# Struts2 with WebSocket connection failed

Tags: java, websocket

Anyone who are familiar with websocket and java EE please help!

I am trying to direct to a .jsp page with websocket implemented using struts2 framework and seems somehow the websocket connection cannot be establish.

I have the following javascript linked to my page

```
window.onload = init;
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/MyFirstWebProject/actions");
socket.onmessage = OnMessage;
socket.onpen = onOpen;

function onOpen(){
    alert(" called1")   
}

function OnMessage(event){

}

function addToOnlineList(user){

}

function init(){
}
```

Server side:

```
    @ApplicationScoped
@ServerEndpoint("/actions")
public class ServerEndPoint{

    @Inject private SessionHandler sessionHandler;

    @OnOpen
    public void OnOpen(Session session){
        System.out.println("User: ");
        sessionHandler.addSession(session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void OnClose(Session session){
        sessionHandler.removeSession(session);
    }

    @OnError
    public void OnError(Throwable error){
        System.out.println(error.toString());
    }
```

I have tried adding

```
   <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="ws://*"/>
```

to the struts.xml to exclude ws: pattern but it still does not work

The problem is the called1 alert was not called, implying the websocket is not established succcessfully, and in the console it gives

```
There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name actions. - [unknown location]
```

error

Comment: What is your JEE container and web server ? It must support websocket protocol.

Comment: I am using glassfish 4.0